# MongoDB caching counters

Tags: caching, mongodb, counter

I'm writing a visit counter for products on a website which uses MongoDB as its' DB-Engine.

[Here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching) it says that Mongo keeps frequently accessed stuff in memory and has an integrated in-memory caching engine.

So can I just relay on this integrated caching system and dumbly set the counters up on every visit or does one still need another caching layer on a high-traffic environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're two seperate things. MongoDB uses a simple paged memory management system that, by design, keeps the most accessed parts of the memory mapped disk space in memory.

As a result, this will help you most for counters that are requested frequently but do not change often. Unfortunately for website counters these two things are mutually exclusive. Because increasing counters will generally not cause MongoDB to move the document holding the counter on disk the read caching will still be fairly effective.

The main issue is your writes, basically doing an increase per visit is not going to be very cost effective. I suggest a strategy where your counter webapp caches incoming visits and only pushes counter updates every X visits or every Y seconds, whichever comes first. Your main goal here is to reduce writes per second so you definitely do not want a db write per counter visit.

Comment: I decided to store ad visits in session and consume them to the server every X minutes or Y pagehits. Dank u wel.

Answer (score 2):

Although ***I have never worked on the kind of system you describe***, I would do the following (assuming that I have read your question correctly and that you do indeed simply want to increment the counter for each visit).

- Use the `$inc` operator to atomically perform the incrementation, or use [upserts with modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers) to create the document structure if it is not already there
- Use an appropriate Write Concern to speed up updates if that is safe to do so (ie with a Write Concern of NONE your call to update will return immediately and you'll just have to trust Mongo to persist it to disk). Of course whether this is safe or not depends on the use case. If you are counting millions of hits then 1 failed hit may not be a problem.
- If the scale of data you are storing is truly enormous, look into using sharding to partition writes